# how to remove [ in object using angularjs

Tags: jquery, arrays, angularjs, object, angularjs-scope

I am new to Angular JS, I want to push one object to another object using angular.
am using push for this:

```
var data = $scope.photosTemp;
```

for example this is one object

```
[{ picture_name="12-Feb-2015_54dc8d6f8786b.png", caption="sadasd", $$hashKey="00G", more...}]
```

if I push the object above to another object, I am getting this result:

```
[Object { picture_name="dummy-logo.png", caption="caption 0", $$hashKey="007", more...}, Object { picture_name="dummy-logo.png", caption="caption 1", $$hashKey="006", more...}, Object { picture_name="dummy-logo.png", caption="caption 2", $$hashKey="005", more...}, Object { picture_name="dummy-logo.png", caption="caption 3", $$hashKey="004", more...}, [Object { picture_name="12-Feb-2015_54dc8e66ba419.png", caption="sffg", $$hashKey="00G", more...}]]
```

I am getting extra `[` brackets for object which I just pushed.

Comment: Post your pushing code with those objects also..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you just want to concatinate the two arrays.

```
var array1 = ["e"]

var array2 = ["a","b","c","d"]

array2 = array2.concat(array1); // this gives ["a","b","c","d","e"]
```

Whereas what you're doing is:

```
array2.push(array1)  // this gives ["a","b","c","d", ["e"]]
```

Comment: But concatinate will always push data at end??

Comment: @chaitra Where did you want it?